# table has more than one primary key Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

I have got error. For start when I create models, I make mistake and give pk for all `id` fields in models. Then I make this right and change for unique, but when I `makemigrations` I get error, I try to delete DB, try to change venv for new, but it do nothing with this error, I think I make mistake in code, but can't find it.

models.py code:

```
class MainContact(models.Model):
    main_contact_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class Tags(models.Model):
    tags_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    tags_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class CustomFiledsValues(models.Model):
    custom_fields_values_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    custom_fields_values_enum = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    custom_fields_values_subtype = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class CustomFields(models.Model):
    custom_fields_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    custom_fields_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    custom_fields_values = models.ForeignKey(CustomFiledsValues, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    custom_fields_is_system = models.BooleanField()

class Contacts(models.Model):
    contact_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)

class Pipeline(models.Model):
    pipeline_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)

class Deal(models.Model):
    deal_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    responsible_user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    account_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField()
    main_contact = models.ForeignKey(MainContact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField()
    closest_task_at = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    custom_fields = models.ForeignKey(CustomFields, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contacts = models.ForeignKey(Contacts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    pipeline = models.ForeignKey(Pipeline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 298, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 117, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/megagun/Projects/venvs/erpmodtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 301, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "amocrmapi_deal" has more than one primary key
```

Comment: try deleting the migration files from `yourapp/migrations/` directory and try migrating again

Comment: Is there any way to show the CREATE TABLE statement that is built from all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of making primary key  for each model because when you create the model by default django create primary key for each model.

```
class Company(models.Model):
   company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

In Company model django by default create Primary key.